# TFS 2015 "Build Job Timeout" results in no logs

Tags: tfs

We have a max execution time set for tests, but frankly this option is about as much use as a chocolate teapot.
[image: Example]

When the execution time exceeds this limit, the whole build fails and all subsequent steps are aborted, so the "Publish Test Results" step never executes, so you get absolutely no information whatsoever to help you work out WHY it exceeded the timeout period.

Can anyone suggest an alternative?
I was thinking of maybe trying to implement the timeout as part of the test code itself - does anyone know if this is possible? If I launch a thread that monitors for the timeout, and if it is hit, then...?
Could I just have the test terminate it's own process?

Comment: What happens when you run all of those tests locally?
You can set "continue on error" for that step.

Comment: Set the timeout on the task itself. You're setting it for the build as a whole, so it logically follows that if the build times out, it stops executing subsequent steps in the build.

Comment: @DanielMann - I see no timeout setting for the "Run Functional Tests" step, am I missing something?

Comment: What test do you run? Basic unit test?

Comment: Not entirely sure how to answer this.
In VS, it is added as a "Unit Test Project".
In TFS, it is run with a "Run Functional Tests" step.

Answer (score 0):

> **Build job timeout in minutes**
>
> Specify the maximum time a build job is allowed to execute on an agent
>   **before being canceled by the server**. Leave it empty or at zero if you want the job to never be canceled by the server.

This timeout are including all tasks in your build definition, if the test step out of time. Then the whole build definition will be canceled by the server. Certainly, the whole build fails and all subsequent steps are aborted.

According to your requirement, suggest you leaving this value 0 and  setting "**continue on error**" for test step just as comment suggested. With this, if the step fails, all following steps are executed and the step/ overall build partially succeeds. Then you could got related info to trouble shoot the failed task.

If your test will not automatically judge whether the execution is timeout or not,  another way is [creating a custom build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task) to collect the execution time of your test task(through read build log), set a judgment to pass of fail the customize step using [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md).

Comment: That would mean building our own timeout into all the tests.  
I was kind of hoping for a way to do this without having to roll our own.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no timeout setting for the built-in  **"Run Functional Tests"** step or **"Visual Studio Test"** step. You may need to add your own timer into all the tests.